# Integrate Google Analytics in NextJS with Twin.Macro / Styled Components Setup: How do I change the _document.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, next.js, styled-components

Have been setting up Next.js with Twin.macro, and for this I had to change the `_document.js` page in Nextjs. Now I'm trying to set up Google Analytics, and I'm following [this tutorial](https://mariestarck.com/add-google-analytics-to-your-next-js-application-in-5-easy-steps/) and it tells me to modify my `_document.js` page to look like this:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          {/* Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics */}
          <script
            async
            src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}`}
          />
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}', {
              page_path: window.location.pathname,
            });
          `,
            }}
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

However, my `_document.js` looks totally different, due to the setup with twin.macro & styled components ([which you can find here](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.examples/tree/master/next-styled-components)) and now I'm a bit lost at what to change?

```
import React from 'react'
import Document from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        })

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      }
    } finally {
      sheet.seal()
    }
  }
}
```

I'm a bit lost here, as I don't really understand what's returned (it seems to return an object here, whereas in the example above it returns some JSX ?) and where and how I am supposed to integrate Google Analytics here now! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Simply add the `render` function to your `MyDocument` class. You don't need to modify anything in `getInitialProps`.

Comment: perfect, thanks a ton!